# How to create alert box in protractor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium, protractor

During testing, I'm trying to put a alert pop up box when my environment is changing from test to prod during executing the scripts in protractor. Can anybody help with me with this?

Comment: You should always add some code to show what you've tried, and others will gladly help

Comment: This is a question that is more of a JS problem and not a protractor issue.

Answer (score 0):

If browser alert popup is acceptable option, you can execute javascript on browser side via protractor api: `browser.executeScript()`.

```
var env_change_alert = "alert('Environment changes from test to prod')";
browser.executeScript(env_change_alert);
```

And you will get popup on the browser with which your test case interact as following:

[image]

The popup will block your test running until you click on the `OK` button on the popup.